# Collecting data doesn't work with Angular.js websites

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-scraping

I am currently writing a program that collects information from a sports website. (it contains the history of some basketball matches) The problem is that the website uses Angular.js for dynamical HTML binding. Consequently, the HTML source code involves lots of variables.

I need to find out the values of the variables in order to make my program work as I want. Is there any library or framework that could help me?

Edit: I am not limited by anything, but I prefer a web app (MEAN, JS frameworks with node-webkit). If it can't be done, I can also code it in C++ or Java (or extend it further to Android with NDK or SDK)

---

*Disclaimer*: This is not grey-hat stuff. I just need to do some web-scraping.

Comment: Please, specify the details on the program, i.e. language, desktop or web app, system requirements.

Comment: try to append `?_escaped_fragment_` to urls, if the site care about SEO, they should support that.

Comment: you can also use prerender by running yourself or use directly prerender.io to get static pages. if you want to implement yourself there is angularjs-server or dive into angularcontext if you want to get low level api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless browser. It will allow you to use JavaScript to get the information you want.

Details:

It will browse to the page you want, execute the JavaScript like any browser and have access to the page as if it was displayed to a normal user using a normal browser. Using JavaScript DOM traversal, you will be able to get the information you need. This is almost the same as automatizing the task of opening a console in a browser and executing javascript which will get the information from the page.

While the below example is really simple, it can do much more than just getting the page results... it can click buttons, navigate to other pages, extract only relevant information, extract the page as an image... Do not hesitate referring to its [Quick start documentation](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html) to learn more about it.

Example script returning the complete HTML page after waiting 10 seconds for the AngularJS to have finished calculating the page:

Command line usage: `phantomjs-1.9.1 this_script.js`

this_script.js (PhantomJS 2.0 may have different syntax in some cases):

```
var url = phantom.args[0]

function getDocumentElementAsHTML(page) {
  return page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.documentElement.innerHTML
  })
}

var page = new WebPage()

page.settings.userAgent = "PhantomJS"

//page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg); }

page.open(url, function (status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network')
    phantom.exit()
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(getDocumentElementAsHTML(page))
      phantom.exit()
    },10000)
  }
});
```

PS: Waiting 10 seconds is not always a great solution, I used to periodically test the existence of the elements I wanted to get information from to be sure the JavaScript finished loading instead.

Source: grey-hat stuff I did in the past

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you'd want to look at http://phantomjs.org/, http://www.slimerjs.org/,  and/or http://casperjs.org/.

Phantom & Slimer give you API access to Webkit and Gecko respectively. Casper adds a more user friendly API over the top.

Comment: Thank you for also bringing Webkit and Gecko in discussion. [bow]

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about slimerjs as an alternative, phantomjs 1.9.1 crashed 0.1% of the time without reason on some machines, I'll consider slimerjs as an alternative if I stumble onto this problem once again :)

Comment: I also noticed that, phantomjs regex implementation is different with real browsers, and got different match results.